# Is NTLDR always present in active partition?

Tags: windows, boot

A question about windows XP boot process. During the process when MBR finds the active partition and then loads the first sector(boot sector) of that(active) partition into memory and then after that boot sector finds and load the NTLDR and so on.

My question is whether the NTLDR and other boot files are always present in the active partition?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Windows to boot up properly, then yes, it should be there :)

If there is no NTLDR file found on the active partition, you will get the `NTLDR is missing` error. Windows looks on the partition marked as **active** for the boot files. If it can't find them, it won't start.

Comment: This answer is now five years out of date.  Windows NT hasn't even *had* an `ntldr` since Windows NT 6.0.